# express.cookieSession() not saving data in the cookies

Tags: session, cookies, parse-platform, session-cookies

I am using parse.com dynamic website to build a product website. I want to use session cookie to store some data in bowser session cookie. Here is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var parseExpressHttpsRedirect = require('parse-express-https-redirect');
var parseExpressCookieSession = require('parse-express-cookie-session');
var app = express();

// Global app configuration section
app.set('views', 'cloud/views');  
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    

app.use(parseExpressHttpsRedirect());
app.use(express.bodyParser());    
app.use(express.cookieParser('YOUR_SIGNING_SECRET'));
app.use(parseExpressCookieSession({
    cookie : {
        maxAge : 3600000
    }
}));

app.use(express.cookieSession());
app.use(app.router);
```

I have this method in app.js which is supposed to returned items added in the cart

```
function getProductsInCart(req) {
    var productsInCart = req.session.productsInCart;

    if(!productsInCart) {
        return [];
    }

    return productsInCart;
}
```

And this is the method which adds a new product in the cart

```
app.get('/add-cart/*', function(req, res) {    
    var url = req.url;
    var productId = url.split('/')[2];

    var productsInCart = getProductsInCart(req);
    productsInCart.push(productId)

    req.session.productsInCart = productsInCart;
    console.log("productsInCart: " + JSON.stringify(productsInCart));    
});
```

The problem i am facing is that getProductsInCart method always returns an empty array, which means that the session is not storing the object in the cookie. This should be simple enough and i can't understand why its not working. Any pointer would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: i filed a bug on parse. Here is it https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/330775347123504/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two things i was doing wrong

1. using req.session instead of req.cookies
2. using cookies as a normal java script objects.

Here is the code that worked

```
app.get('/add-cart/*', function(req, res) {
    var url = req.url;
    var productId = url.split('/')[2];

    var productsInCart = getProductsInCart(req);
    console.log("productsInCart: " + JSON.stringify(productsInCart));

    productsInCart.push(productId);
    res.cookie('productsInCart', productsInCart, {
        signed: false,
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1000000)
    });

    res.send(req.cookies);
});

function getProductsInCart(req) {
    var productsInCart = req.cookies.productsInCart;

    if(!productsInCart) {
        return [];
    }

    return productsInCart;
}
```